# Transferring the Github Organization ownership

Tags: github, organization, ownership

There is a way to transfer the ownership of the repositories in github, but is there is a way to transfer the ownership of a organization completely?

What Github presntly has is a way to add multiple people to the organization's Owners team. And also any owner can be removed from the team by the user who created the organization in the first place. Is there a way to remove that user, and transfer complete control to someone who is there in the team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transfer ownership of anything (including a repository, actually) to a different user, you need to [contact support](https://github.com/contact).

Comment: @Sidincious: Thank you, I have previously don transfers, but they were between myself and my organization, hence I didn't run into any issue.

Comment: FYI: GitHub support no longer needs to be contacted; you can handle this yourself in the settings or with an API call