# Who is allowed to transfer a repo ownership

Tags: github

I created a repo for an organization, not for me. When creating the repo I put the email (or the github handle, I dont remember now) of my boss.

Now I am being asked to transfer the ownership of the repo, and I get an error

```
You can only transfer a repository from an organization to yourself at this time
```

What does this mean?

Thank you

To clarify, I created this repo with an email that is not from the company, so I am an "Outside collaborator".

Can I transfer a repo I created for an organization, being that I am an outside collaborator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8736830/62576

Comment: @KenWhite that really doesn't answer my question. It is in fact possible to make transfers without contacting support, and I don't want to transfer ownership of the whole organization as that questions states, only of that repo. Furthermore the answer is outdated and no longer valid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it by doing 2 transfers:

1. I transferred it to my personal github
2. From there I transferred it to where I wanted originally

for some reason this works, but transferring directly not